# What happens when a connection is closed mid-transaction?

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions

I'm using `SQLServer` along with Springs `JtaTransactionManager`.

Given a method like this:

```
@Transactional
public void something() {
    try (final Connection conn1 = getConnection()) {
        //insert/update stuff in database
    }


    try (final Connection conn2 = getConnection()) {
        //insert/update stuff in database
    }
}
```

Will this method actually be transactional? What happens to the changes made when `conn1` gets closed, are they commited to the database? What happens if an exception occurs while working with `conn2`, can the changes made through a closed connection be rolled back?

Comment: I think you are misusing  `@Transactional`, you shouldn't create connection on your own inside it

Comment: What driver are you using? As the javadoc states [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()) these things are `implementation-defined`.

Comment: Needed to double-check, turns out it's not transactional, but @TransactionAttribute. So it might be JavaEE, but the project uses a mix of JavaEE and Spring so a bit hard to know. It's LEGACY code (so legacy that it needs to be written in all caps.)

Comment: This question is an attempt to generalize this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376413/transactionmanagement-with-glassfish-spring-xa-and-jta

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't load/get connection or datasource manually inside `@Transactional`, especially when using [JtaTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-strategies)

> The **JtaTransactionManager does not need to know about the DataSource, or any other specific resources**, because it uses the container’s global transaction management infrastructure.

Comment: I'm not sure how that quote relates to my question. I'm looking to figure out what happens when you are in a transaction, and connections are being closed.

Comment: @Tobb you shouldn't update connection inside `@Transactional`, all method should be using same connection

Comment: I'm aware that I shoudn't. The guys who made the code I'm working on, not so much. Which is why I'm trying to figure out how this actually works.

Comment: @Tobb if you don't explicit call commit on connection and auto commit is set to false so it won't commit transaction inside method

Comment: Ok, there is no explicit commit as far as I can see. Not sure about auto-commit, but since changes are in fact made to the database I assume it is on.

Comment: The connection is provided by the transactionmanager. As soon as it is created it takes part in the XA-Transaction it handles. So the Transactionmanager handles the complete lifecycle of Database-Connections, at least as long as you use XA-Resources or JTA-Resources, They register with the transactionmanager.